# Can't able to scrape the airtel website plans with python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get("https://www.airtel.in/myplan-infinity/")

  
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
  
#finding the div with the id
div_bs4 = soup.find('div')
print(div_bs4)
```

What should I do to scrape the recharge plans of the page?

Comment: Use selenium or Playwright  - BS is not suitable for sites that load data via javascript api's

Answer (score 0):

you should use `content` when you need to get media data (like pictures, videos, etc)
if you need to get non-media data you've to use `text` instead of `content`

make the soup like this: `soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

make sure that this like `div_bs4 = soup.find('div')` finds the exact `div` you need (cuz it will just get the first div in html)

this line `print(div_bs4)` won't give you needed data 
you'd better use this `print(div_bs4.text)`